# @grid MVC convert date to local timezone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, date, gridview

I have an MVC Grid that shows the transactions stored in the DB. One of its column is a date and that date is stored in UTC format and upon display I need to convert it to the browser timezone.

```
@grid.GetHtml(        
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "transactionsGrid" },       
        columns:grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("TransactionDate", ((grid.SortColumn == "TransactionDate" ? (grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▲ " : "▼ ") : "") + "Date"), style: "TransactionDate")
        )
```

How can I acheive this? how can I do this with javascript since it should be handled on the client side.

Thanks in advance.

EDITED

I figured out how to do it:

```
@grid.GetHtml(        
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "transactionsGrid" },       
        columns:grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("TransactionDate", ((grid.SortColumn == "TransactionDate" ? (grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▲ " : "▼ ") : "") + "Date"), style: "TransactionDate", format: (item) => new HtmlString("<div name='date' data-datetime='"+item.TransactionDate+"'>"+item.TransactionDate+"</div>"))
```

and Here is the javascript code:

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
        var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        var hours = date.getHours();
        newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
        return newDate;
    }

    Date.prototype.format = function (format) {
        var o = {
            "M+": this.getMonth() + 1, //month
            "d+": this.getDate(),    //day
            "h+": this.getHours(),   //hour
            "m+": this.getMinutes(), //minute
            "s+": this.getSeconds(), //second
            "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3),  //quarter
            "S": this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
        }

        if (/(y+)/.test(format)) format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
          (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
        for (var k in o) if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format))
            format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
              RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] :
                ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
        return format;
    }
    $("div[name=date]").each(function () {
        var myDate = new Date($(this).data("datetime"));
        var convertToLocalDate = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(myDate);
        $(this).text(convertToLocalDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    });
```

Comment: you should consider adding your solution as an answer and then mark it as such to complete this post.

Comment: Wow... this is a lot of work.. It would be nicer if this were possible on the grid itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it:

```
@grid.GetHtml(        
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "transactionsGrid" },       
        columns:grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("TransactionDate", ((grid.SortColumn == "TransactionDate" ? (grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "▲ " : "▼ ") : "") + "Date"), style: "TransactionDate", format: (item) => new HtmlString("<div name='date' data-datetime='"+item.TransactionDate+"'>"+item.TransactionDate+"</div>"))
```

and Here is the javascript code:

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
        var newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
        var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        var hours = date.getHours();
        newDate.setHours(hours - offset);
        return newDate;
    }

    Date.prototype.format = function (format) {
        var o = {
            "M+": this.getMonth() + 1, //month
            "d+": this.getDate(),    //day
            "h+": this.getHours(),   //hour
            "m+": this.getMinutes(), //minute
            "s+": this.getSeconds(), //second
            "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3),  //quarter
            "S": this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
        }

        if (/(y+)/.test(format)) format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
          (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
        for (var k in o) if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format))
            format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
              RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] :
                ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
        return format;
    }
    $("div[name=date]").each(function () {
        var myDate = new Date($(this).data("datetime"));
        var convertToLocalDate = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(myDate);
        $(this).text(convertToLocalDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
    });
```